# Como ter uma pesquisa mais precisa e ignorando caracteres especiais usando typeahead.js (Script de auto-completar)

Tags: javascript, typeahead

Vou deixar aqui uma modificação que encontrei para o script typeahead.js pois pode ser útil se alguém estiver precisando da mesma solução,

O scritp atual para o campo "modulo-1" já deve funcionar perfeitamente para muita gente, pois ele te dá a opção de você buscar algo ignorando acentos ou caracteres especiais, e isso pode ser personalizavel.

HTML:

```html
Módulo 1:<br>
<input id="modulo-1" class="typeahead" type="text">
<br>
<br>
Módulo 2:<br>
<input id="modulo-2" class="typeahead" type="text">

<script  type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// modulo-1
// ----------
var charMap = {
    "à": "a",
    "á": "a",
    "â": "a",
    "é": "e",
    "è": "e",
    "ê": "e",
    "ë": "e",
    "É": "e",
    "ï": "i",
    "î": "i",
    "ô": "o",
    "ö": "o",
    "û": "u",
    "ù": "u",
    "ü": "u",
    "ñ": "n"    
};

var names = ["série:Aladdin", "personagem:Naruto","paródia:Dragon Ball Z"];

var normalize = function (input) {
    $.each(charMap, function (unnormalizedChar, normalizedChar) {
        var regex = new RegExp(unnormalizedChar, 'gi');
        input = input.replace(regex, normalizedChar);
    });
    return input;
};

var queryTokenizer = function (q) {
    var normalized = normalize(q);
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(normalized);
};

var nombres = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: queryTokenizer,
    local: $.map(names, function (name) {
        // Normalize the name - use this for searching
        var normalized = normalize(name);
        return {
            value: normalized,
            // Include the original name - use this for display purposes
            displayValue: name
        };
    })
});

nombres.initialize();

$('#modulo-1').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    hint: false,
    highlight: true
}, {
    displayKey: 'displayValue',
    source: nombres.ttAdapter()
});







// modulo-2
// ----------
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring q
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring q, add it to the matches array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ["série:Aladdin", "personagem:Naruto","paródia:Dragon Ball Z"];

$('#modulo-2').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
                         {
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avcurdgy/2/

Temos 2 campos, "modulo-1" e "modulo-2"

No módulo-1, está quase do jeito que eu quero, nele eu consigo buscar "série" ou "serie" e ele me dá o valor que preciso. Mas quando eu busco "naruto" ele não retorna nada.

Agora no "modulo-2" quando eu busco "naruto" ele consegue achar o resultado, mas ele não ignora os acentos, se eu buscar por "serie" ele não retorna nada.

Eu preciso que no módulo-1 quando eu buscar por "naruto" ele encontre o resultado como no módulo-2, tentei bastante aqui por vários dias, mas sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia me dar uma força?

Documentação do typeahead.js: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Fontes: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/271

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema que não dependa de nenhum recurso externo, explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Comment: Vale notar que seu fiddle está tirando os acentos do digitado, obviamente que não vai encontrar coisas com acento. Bastou remover sua função normalize que o acento passou a ser encontrado: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZrx9.png - Mas de qualquer forma os links passados servem para eventuais futuras perguntas.

Comment: Considerando que os comentários estão se estendendo além da finalidade, e já foi passado tudo que é necessário, a discussão [foi migrada para um chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152207/) para evitar acumular ruído. O importante é observar o primeiro comentário, e no lugar do código com o bug que você mesmo criou, postar um [mcve]. Isso pode ajudar bastante. O resto já está todo explicado acima também, espero que ajude.